# How to validate only the class-level annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I have a class `ClueRequest` with a validator on every property and also with class-level annotation. I want to validate only the class-level validator, something like:

`validator.validateProperty(objectToValidate, nameProperty)` on a property.

How can I do that?

```java
@TypeListValidationConstraint(nameTypeField = "type", enumClass = inductilTypes.class, nameListField = "values")
public class ClueRequest {
    @NotNullCustom(nameAttribut = "valueId")
    private String valueId;
    @NotNullCustom(nameAttribut = "analogy")
    private Boolean analogy;
    @NotNullCustom(nameAttribut = "open")
    private Boolean open;
```

Comment: by "@TypeListValidationConstraint" do you mean that you want to create that annotation to make your own custom validations?